# why gcc embedded gcov library by JPL NASA is not creating full gcda data on STM32F429 target memory?

Tags: gcov

I am using embedded gcov library from JPL/NASA to get code coverage on my stme32f429 target using Embitz IDE and gcc compiler v5.4. The link is shared below:

https://github.com/nasa-jpl/embedded-gcov

However, it seems that gcov_*conver-togcda() functions is not producing full gcda coverage data because It is not entering a for loop. I am only getting fixed 12 bytes of gcda data that should be more than that, including coverage counters information. My debugging efforts showed that number of instrumented functions variable of gcc handled gcov*_ *info structure is always 0. Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here? Please feel free to see the attachments.*[image][image]

I wanted to see the instrumented code generated by gcc gcov to ensure that it is instrumenting my source code with coverage counters. I am able to compile code with -ftest-coverage and -fprofile-arcs compiler options.